# What are good resources for a professional programmer to learn Canvas and SVG API?

Tags: html, canvas, svg

I want to dive deep into canvas and svg capabilities of modern browsers. I was wondering what are some good online tutorials, videos and books that would help someone with a programming background to start building non-trivial canvas and svg application.

Also what would be some well designed canvas/svg frameworks and libraries that one could use for reference.

Answer (score 2):

For canvas, I would recommend [Dive Into HTML5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/).
For SVG, you can find some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333367/learning-svg).

Answer (score 2):

+1 Gaurav. "Dive into HTML5" is a great intro to `canvas`. Additionally, David Flanagan also has a new book, "Canvas Pocket Reference," which doubles as a tutorial: http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781449396800/.

Also, I recently took an SVG course through the W3C and the entire course used its [official primer](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html) as the class text. I'd definitely recommend that; its got tons of examples to follow.

Lastly, check out Raphaël, a JS library to simply work with vector graphics -- http://raphaeljs.com/

Comment: If you want to visualize datasets also check out D3.js, http://mbostock.github.com/d3/.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of more Canvas related resources you might find handy:

- http://easeljs.com/, wraps Canvas and provides some extra goodies
- https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js, you can do cool 3D stuff with canvas too (no need to wait for WebGL)
- http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/, assorted collection of HTML5 Canvas Tutorials
- http://billmill.org/static/canvastutorial/, nice and interactive tutorial to Canvas

Hopefully those will help. :)